# click link to travel to another html file you created

Tags: html

I am trying to make a website for my own personal use. Is it possible to create a link that opens another html file that you created?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="PathToTheFile">Link</a>
```

Where PathToTheFile is the path relative to the page you're on. So if you are at home.htm and want to link to about.htm, your link will look like this:

```
<a href="about.htm">About</a>
```